# Having issues with if/else I end up with two output files

Tags: powershell

Having issues with if/else I end up with two output files, I just need 
C:\$UserName-$ComputerName-OpenPSTs-$Date.csv if a PST exists and to include details.

or C:\$UserName-$ComputerName-NOPSTs-$Date.csv if no PST exist with "No PSTs Found" written in the file.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

```
#---------------------------------h 
#Getting date and system variables
#---------------------------------
$Date = Get-Date -format d-M-yyyy
$UserName = $env:USERNAME
$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME

#-------------------------------
#Launch Outlook and check stores
#-------------------------------
$Outlook = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application
$Object = $Outlook.Session.Stores | % {    

#-------------------
#Check if PSTs exist
#-------------------
If ($_.FilePath -like "*.PST") { 

#------------------------------------------------------------
#If PST exsists then collect data and build CSV column labels
#------------------------------------------------------------ 
$_ | Select `
@{Expression={$_.DisplayName}; Label="PST Name in Outlook"},`
@{Expression={$_.FilePath}; Label="PST Location/FileName"},`
@{Expression={$_.IsOpen}; Label="PST Open in Outlook"},`
@{Expression={(Get-Item $_.FilePath).Length / 1KB}; Label="PST File Size (KB)"}
$Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'ComputerName' -Value $ComputerName
$Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'UserName' -Value $UserName

#--------------------------------------
#Output PST and User information to log
#--------------------------------------
$Object | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation C:\$UserName-$ComputerName-OpenPSTs-$Date.csv

#-----------------------------------------
#If no PST exsists then create file NOPSTs
#-----------------------------------------
$Text = "No PSTs Found" 
} Else {
$_ | Select $Text | Out-File C:\$UserName-$ComputerName-NOPSTs-$Date.csv
  }
}

#---------------
#Closing Outlook
#---------------
Start-Sleep 5
Get-Process | Where {$_.Name -like "Outlook*"} | Stop-Process
```

Comment: It would be nice if you'd accept the answer to your previous question (or clarify the question if the answer wasn't satisfying) before asking a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
$Text = "No PSTs Found" 
} Else {
$_ | Select $Text | Out-File C:\$UserName-$ComputerName-NOPSTs-$Date.csv
  }
```

with this:

```
} Else {
  'No PSTs Found' | Out-File C:\$UserName-$ComputerName-NOPSTs-$Date.csv
}
```

Comment: Hello Thank you for the suggestions so far. The data is now being populated in the files correctly but still end up with two files. I have a PST configured in my outlook so should only have the OpenPSTs file created. If no pst configured in Outlook then only the NoPSTs file is created which is correct. Thanks for any suggestions you can provide.

Comment: @kuat: Do you mean that you want the NoPST file to be created only when there are no PST files anywhere?

Comment: The NoPST works fine, no pst configured in otlook and only C:\$UserName-$ComputerName-NOPSTs-$Date.csv is created. It is the other way round when both files are created, so pst configured in outlook and both C:\$UserName-$ComputerName-OpenPSTs-$Date.csv and C:\$UserName-$ComputerName-NOPSTs-$Date.csv are created.

Comment: @kuat: Looks to me like `$Outlook.Session.Stores` returns at least one store with no PST. Another thing is you assign the pipeline output to the variable `$object` while also using the same variable *inside* the loop. Do one or the other, but not both.